# Two and four digit year handling in a date form field in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, date, datetime

In a Symfony form about a user's profile I'd like to present the user's birthdate in the form `dd.MM.yyyy`, e.g.: `31.05.1983`. However, I want the application to handle cases, where the user does not enter the full version of the birthdate, gracefully, e.g.: `31.5.83` shall be converted to `31.05.1983`.

In the form I added the following field:

```
$form->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', [
    'input' => 'datetime',
    'view_timezone' => 'UTC',
    'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'required' => false,
])
```

Note: I added the `'view_timezone' => 'UTC'` option value because the birthdate is parsed to a `DateTime` (by Symfony) and transformed to UTC (by me) and I want to avoid any date flipping due to timezone conversion. PHP is configured to the default timezone `CET` which is one hour ahead of `UTC`.

With this form field when someone enters the date `31.05.1983` everything is fine. In the normalized form you will get a `DateTime` with the contents `1983-05-31 00:00:00`.

However, when someone enters `31.5.83` into this form field you will get a `DateTime` with the contents `0083-05-28 23:38:00`. Note: not only is the year set to 83 but also date day has changed from 31 to 28.

I can understand the year part because the date parser cannot know with certainty what was meant here. However, the day part I cannot understand.

I would like to implement the following behaviour: if the user enters a year smaller than 100 then apply some manual guessing logic for example in a `FormEvents::SUBMIT` event handler. (E.g.: If the entered year is smaller or equal than the last two digits of the current year then add 2000 else add 1900.)

However, if I cannot be sure about the day and month part of the date then how can i correctly "fix" such a date?

Does someone know (an elegant) way to tackle this?

Comment: In `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` EventListener do your logic on the submitted string and reformat it with the final Date. Then the internal logic will validate correctly.

Comment: Or use a data transformer on your date field : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#simple-example-sanitizing-html-on-user-input

Comment: I would set the entity date field to require a strictly formatted string, no guessing. Then whoever is submitting the data has to make it conform or get an exception. Then, with your form, use Javascript to enforce (and assist) the user to create the correct date string.